# How to block ip forwarding for specific remote ip address

Tags: networking, iptables, ip, ufw

I use ubuntu as gateway for several hosts. I need advise how to block ip forwarding for specific ip address or specific ip range?

I tried to block ip via ufw deny rules, but it looks like ip forwarding settings cannot be modified via rules and it can be applied only globally (DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY in /etc/default/ufw)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in the *filter section of `/etc/ufw/before.rules`

```
-A ufw-before-forward -o eth0 -d xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/xxx -j REJECT
```

This will discard packet before forward